# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (57, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am working with the LSTM model and getting this error.

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (57, 1)

Here is my code:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, input_shape = (700, 57), return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
             loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
history = model.fit(train_data, batch_size=32, epochs=60, verbose=2, validation_data=valid_data)
model.save("LSTM.h5")
```

The shape of my training data is:

```
input_shape = (x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print(input_shape)

((700, 57), (700,))
```

The training dataset contains 700 rows (samples) and 57 columns (features) and the test dataset contains labels for 700 samples.

Comment: `input_shape` specified to a layer does not include batch dimension. Try `input_shape = (57,)`

Comment: @bui Nope getting this error: ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_4 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 57)

Comment: LSTM expects an input of three dimensions, namely `(batch, timestep, features)`. Is each sample of yours a length-1 sequence? In that case, you'll need to set `input_shape = (1,57)` and reshape your data as `x_train = x_train[:, None, :]` and `x_validation = x_validation[:, None, :]`

Comment: The new shape of `x_train` is `(700, 1, 1, 1, 57)`. Now I am getting this error: ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_7 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (57, 1)

Comment: The error is the same.

Comment: How did `x_train` go from `(700,57)` to `(700,1,1,1,57)` just after `x_train = x_train[:, None, :]`? Did you forget to reload x_train and keep on expanding its dimension? `x_train` should be of shape `(700,1,57)` and `input_shape` should be `(1,57)`

Comment: Sorry I didn't run the last cell of my notebook. Now the new shape of `x_train` is `(700, 1, 57)`. But getting the same error: ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_8 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (57, 1)

Comment: What is your `train_data`? Is it not the same as `(x_train, y_train)`? Did you reconstruct `train_data` after modifying `x_train`?

Comment: `train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))`

Comment: i am using this function `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`. Docstring:
Creates a `Dataset` whose elements are slices of the given tensors.

The given tensors are sliced along their first dimension. This operation
preserves the structure of the input tensors, removing the first dimension
of each tensor and using it as the dataset dimension. All input tensors
must have the same size in their first dimensions.

Comment: The error is that somehow the dataset is feeding your model an input of shape `(None, 57, 1)` even though you have already reshape `x_train`. Did you remember to call `train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))` **after** updating `x_train = x_train[:, None, :]`?

Comment: I have changed the fit command to: `history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=60, verbose=2, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))`. The problem with the `input_shape` is resolved but now at fit command, this error occurs: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_13 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 57)`

Comment: Now the code outputs the model summary which is just one line above the `fit()`. I think now the problem occurs with the `y_test`. Show this error: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_13 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 57)`

Comment: Did you expand the dimension of `x_val` like how you did with `x_train`?

Comment: Error solved! I didn't change the shape of `x_val`. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LSTM expects an input of three dimensions, namely `(batch, timestep, features)`. Is each sample of yours a length-1 sequence? In that case, you'll need to set `input_shape = (1,57)` and reshape your data as `x_train = x_train[:, None, :]` and `x_validation = x_validation[:, None, :]`